# Issue copying DIV with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to copy a DIV to an image using html2canvas and function toDataURL, but it does not work. 
Basically, content of DIV id="printableArea" should be converted to an image and appear in DIV id="theimage"
Has anyone an idea why it does not work?
simplified code below or full jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdugert/cd3wezho/27/):

basic code:

```
<br>
<image id="theimage"></image>
<br>
---------------
<br>
<div class='container' id="printableArea">
   ... where the magic is built ...
</div>
```

and the JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('printableArea');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

document.getElementById("theimage").src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: `printableArea` is not a canvas tag`(div != canvas)`. Try with canvas tag

Comment: var canvas = document.getElementById('printableArea'); does in theory pass the DIV to a canvas object isn't it?

Comment: Just because you _name_ a variable `canvas`, does not mean the value you assign _becomes_ a canvas element/object. This is not how that works. You mention html2canvas, but you are not even using that in the code snippet you have shown … maybe time you go read up on the documentation for that on how it is actually used.